# What is the purpose of this MySQL procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

There are procedures as below for a lot of things. What are the benefits of doing this? Are there any security benefits?

```
 DELIMITER //
    CREATE
        DEFINER = 'webappuser'@'localhost' PROCEDURE find_number_users()
        SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) as total_users FROM user WHERE userCost = 1;
    END;
    //
    DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: A stored procedure can be used to a) hide implementation details from code that calls it, b) shorten/simplify code that calls it, and c) both of the above.

Comment: Pros? Between very little and none.  Cons? A laundry list.

Comment: @Bohemian are there any security pros?

Comment: "any security pros?", much closer to none. Avoid stored procedures until you have a driving use case/requirement.

Comment: It is useful for re-usability, it improves code readability and it also adds a security layer with access control.

Answer (score 1):

Procedures can be used to implement some simple security mechanisms.

If a procedure is defined with `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` then it runs with the grants of the definer. This allows you to restrict access to some databases or tables, but then allow restricted users to execute procedures that access them. So they can't write arbitrary queries that access the tables, but they can get the data in ways that are controlled by the database administrator who defines the procedures.

The procedure you showed has `SQL SECURITY INVOKER`, so it doesn't take advantage of this feature.

This can also be done with views.